# How do I debug / catch errors for D3

Tags: javascript, debugging, d3.js

Working through a project on developing some fairly simple graphs, and I'm finding I'm missing some fairly simple (but not obvious) errors. I'm using Intellij and it's internal debug isn't picking up the issues. Examples are:

```
> d3.json("data/revenue.json").then(function(data){
>     console.log(data);
```

The error? Well it's `"data/revenues.json` a simple typo that hasn't been picked up.

How do can this picked up in console without having to catch at every line?

Comment: Use a browser with developer tools that allow you to step through the code and examine the values of variables during execution; use code linters to eliminate typos; write tests during development to ensure that your code does what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to catch this, and other errors is to place

```
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
})
```

at the end of your code, for the above example the chrome console will produce the below errors

> Error: 404 File not found
>       at Re (d3.min.js:2)

**alternatively**

As mentioned by user @i alarmed

Use a browser with developer tools that allows you to step through the code and examine the values of variables during execution; use code linters to eliminate typos; write tests during development to ensure that your code does what you think it is doing.